# How to display my Google Cloud Speech usage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I have tried Google Cloud Speech with Python and it works quite well. However, it is a paid service and I really have to know not only totals (they are in the invoice I have received and on the billing page of Google Console). But mainly how the final price is constructed interests me, in order to optimize the code, particularly size of recognition chunks. After digging in the console I have found "IAM & admin - Quotas", but it still only summarizes audio seconds per day, when their docs page states that each request is rounded up to next 15 seconds for billing - you cannot deduce cost by that.

Counting the data on my end, in addition to being superfluous, does not seem to lead to exact results anyway. Google has this data, this is obvious from the data on the quotas page. Is there any way to get this data with some Google API?

Comment: Have you had a chance to study the documentation on billing found here ... https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/ ?   The data relating to billing can be exported to BigQuery and then queries executed.

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of data I was after. Though short, this is exactly the answer, so if you make it such, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is an API for billing, it is used to manage billing as opposed to gain information about your utilization.  What Google does provide is a mechanism to export your billing data to a BigQuery table from which you can execute a variety of SQL queries and visualizations.  Documentation on performing this step can be found here:

[Export Billing Data to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery)